# Want to program app to connect to bluetooth device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Hopefully someone can send me in the right direction.

I am attempting to program a simple app that connects via bluetooth to a piece of fire alarm equipment. The overall goal is that when the fire alarm is triggered on the equipment, the app shows the fire alarm status via simple binary Alarm/No alarm function.

What I am having trouble with is programming the bluetooth function. I have experience with Java but not with a bluetooth functionality. I want to program a button that searches and connects to bluetooth devices.

Here is the bit of code I've started in MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val daqButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.daqButton)

        daqButton.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code I've started in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <!-- If your app targets Android 9 or lower, you can declare
         ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION instead. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any tips or tricks to help me accomplish this is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest way to implement that is to use a third-party library like this [Bluetooth Library](https://github.com/OmarAflak/Bluetooth-Library).

- Include the library dependency into your `app module` gradle file.
- set up the library in your app as described in the library's repository on GitHub.
- If you need to connect to the device from the app you have to implement the scanning functionality yourself by providing a `ListView` and the logic to insert the discovered Bluetooth devices. *Refer to the Github repository documentation* you will find some callbacks that you can use to implement the search, discovery, and connection functionalities.
- If you prefer to follow the easy way just connect to the Bluetooth device externally from your device's Bluetooth manager, then you can communicate with the device as follows.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    bluetooth = new Bluetooth(this);
    bluetooth.send("Your message");

}
```

- If you want to receive back some response from the other Bluetooth device you have to listen to the `DeviceCallback()` *you will find its description in the Github repository*

### Note

You have to add some permissions in the Manifest files which are

- BLUETOOTH
- BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
- ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

In order to give access to your app to use the Bluetooth

- You can follow this [example code](https://github.com/OmarAflak/Bluetooth-Library/tree/master/app/src/main/java/me/aflak/libraries) provided by the library

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will browse the github link you dropped but perhaps just utilizing the devices built in bluetooth manager might be the best course of action.